# No matching function for call to constructor with reference parameter

Tags: c++, templates

In the following example, I have two classes which are the same, except that the first uses a template.

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
    const T t;

    public:

    Container(const T _t): t(_t) { }    

    const T get() {
        return t;
    }
};


class PersonContainer {
    const Person& p;

    public:

    PersonContainer(const Person& _p): p(_p) { }    

    const Person& get() {
        return p;
    }
};
```

Here's the `Person` class referred to:

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    Person(int _age): age(_age) {}; 
};
```

When I pass an rValue to a function expecting a lValue, it works fine in the non-template class's constructor (since it's a constant param). However, for the templated classes it fails:

```
int main() {    
    PersonContainer personContainer(Person(50));  // works fine
    Container<Person&> container(Person(50));  // error
    cout << personContainer.get().age;
    cout << container.get().age;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Container<Person&>::Container(Person)’
```

I'm curious to find out why the templated class does not behave the same way as the regular class.

Comment: ... reference as typename?

Comment: Why are you trying to hold a reference to an object that is destroyed after the construction of the containers. This will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how the const binds to T.

What it ends up with is a const reference to T. References are const by default so that makes no difference. Meaning that your constructor expects a T& to which the temporary can't bind(see your other question). 
What you were expecting is a reference to a const T.

```
T = Person&
(const T == Person& const == Person&) != const Person&
```

I hope this makes sense.

As a reply to your comment on the other answer, you should simply take `Person` as a template parameter and make your `get` function return `const T&`.

In addition, storing references might be dangerous as your "container" might outlive the actual object to which the reference points.

Comment: I considered that, but I wanted to keep a reference to `T` inside the `Container` to avoid the copy associated with `t(_t)` member initialization.

Comment: @jeffreyveon Then simply keep a `const T&` in your class. However, watch out for lifetime issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container<Person&> container(Person(50));
```

You should remove & from type you are passing to template as it's irrelevant in this context.

```
Container<Person> container(Person(50));
```

Comment: Doing that would not allow me to return the `t` member as a reference. I would like that as it would indicate that I don't want the object to be deleted by the consumer of the API.